# How to size v-card and v-tile in small screens

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, responsive

I am trying to use VCard and Vlist tile to achieve the below mock in all the screens.

[image]

But as soon as breakpoint hits xs the tile component breaks and overflows the card instead of auto-scaling the child components down.
[image]
Is there any cleaner way to approach this problem using vuetify classes, any suggestions would be helpful

This is what i have tried till now

```
    <v-layout row style="max-height:60vh !important;">
    <v-flex
      xs6
      sm6
      offset-sm3
      offset-xs3
    >
      <v-card class="mx-auto">
        <v-card-title class="mx-0 px-2">
          <v-list-tile
            class="grow page-header ma-0 pa-0"
            :key="item.title"
            avatar
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-tile-avatar size="60">
              <img :src="item.avatar">
            </v-list-tile-avatar>

            <v-list-tile-content class="ml-2">
              <v-list-tile-title
                v-html="item.pageName"
                class="page-name pb-0 mb-0 text-truncate"
              />
            </v-list-tile-content>
            <v-layout align-center justify-end>
              <v-icon medium class="mr-0 pr-0">
                more_horiz
              </v-icon>
            </v-layout>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text class="pa-0">
          <v-layout row wrap class="pa-0">
            <v-flex
              xs12
              md12
              sm12
              class="pa-2 body-1"
            >
              {{ item.postText }}
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 md12 sm12>
              <v-img :src="item.avatar" />
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions class="red lighten-1">
          <v-list-tile class="grow" :key="item.title" @click="">
            <v-list-tile-content class="red lighten-1">
              <v-list-tile-title
                class="page-name pb-0 mb-0 text-truncate font-weight-bold"
              >
                {{ item.title }}
              </v-list-tile-title>
              <v-list-tile-sub-title class="pt-1 mt-0 text-truncate">
                {{ item.subtitle }}
              </v-list-tile-sub-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
            <v-layout align-center justify-end class="red lighten-1">
              <v-btn flat outline>
                BUY
              </v-btn>
            </v-layout>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/yLgPdeX